# Database Migration using library

Tags: database, postgresql, go, migrate

I was trying to migrate database schema to POSTGRESQL using the code below
BUT it does not work, it returned an error

> "source driver: unknown driver file (forgotten import?)"

And it worked well using CLI

`Up.sql` and `down.sql` files are in dbMigration folder

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate"
)

func main() {
    mg, err := migrate.New(
        "file://dbMigration",
        "postgres://username:localhost:5432/databasename?sslmode=disable",
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err = mg.Up; err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use database packages in go, you usually need to import the driver separately.

That's also what the error is trying to tell you.

```
source driver: unknown driver file (forgotten import?)
```

In golang-migrate, you can import the driver from their repository.

```golang
import (
    "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4"
    _ "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/database/postgres"
    _ "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/source/github"
)
```

This is also documented in their [readme](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate#use-in-your-go-project).